# Magento 2 - can't save changes to product

Tags: magento2, product, admin, backend, save

I try to change some product info text and then save, but after it saves, the text in the backend/frontend still remains the same. There is no error showing.

What can I do?

---

## Additional Information

I am using Magento 2.4.2 Enterprise

This shows if I save the product, first I thought it is not related, so I did not mentioned it, but maybe it is:

[image]

**exception.log:**

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'company_m2.amasty_elastic_relevance_rule_index' doesn't exist

I already executed `bin/magento setup:upgrade` but the error remains.

Comment: which magento edition are you using?

Comment: 2.4.2 Enterprise

Comment: is it possible that you have some content staging campaign or something?

Comment: No. I added more informations.

Comment: check what's going on with that extension, and why does it look for a table that doesn't exist. maybe the extension is not added properly or the extension is removed but code not regenerated.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why, but after executing `composer update` and then `setup:upgrade` and `setup:di:compile` it works again.

Comment: yaaay! glad to hear this :)